# Navigating through a JSON API tree using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use a JSON api and retrieve some data. I'm still new to it though and I can't seem to figure out which value to use. My JSON API looks something like this:

```
[
   {"lang":"english","visual":"<span>Text</span>","weight":0.92},
   {"lang":"swedish","visual":"<span>Text</span>","weight":0.22},
   //etc
]
```

and my jQuery is:

```
     $.getJSON(url ,function(data) {
            $.each(data.lang, function(i, item) {
                dataName = item["visual"];
                        console.log(dataName);
            });
        });
```

but nothing is being logged. How do I navigate through a JSON tree? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.lang` is undefined. `lang` is a property of each object in the array of objects that data holds. Simply iterate the data array, each object will contain the visual property (as well as lang);

```
$.getJSON(url ,function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        var lang = this["lang"];
        var dataName = this["visual"];
        console.log(dataName);
    });
});
```